# What happen to Nana and Kakeru in The Knight in the Area after the anime ends?

Tags: the-knight-in-the-area

I have watched *The Knight in the Area*, but I'm curious as to what has happened since the end of the anime until the latest chapter in the manga.

My questions are as follows:

- Do Nana and Kakeru ever get together?
- Do they win a championship?
- Is there a better understanding as to why Suguru can take over Kakeru?
- Does Kakeru become the best scorer/forward in the nation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After the Japanese Olympic team wins the test match against Frankfurt and with Yuusuke's support<sup>[[1]](http://areanokishi.wikia.com/wiki/Kakeru_Aizawa/Relationships#cite_note-0)</sup>, Kakeru finally confesses to Nana. She then cries in happiness while saying that her feelings were never one-sided. The two finally kiss under the evening sky, where their friendship finally turned to romance even after graduating from Enoshima High. In the epilogue, Kakeru made it into the World Cup final. On the eve of the final, Kakeru was approached by Nana with a ring on her finger, revealing their engagement.

Source: http://areanokishi.wikia.com/wiki/Kakeru_Aizawa/Relationships